# How do I check if a json key exists in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, psycopg2

Let's say I have a json that looks like this:

```
some_json = {'key_a': {'nested_key': 'a'},
             'key_b': {'nested_key': 'b'}}
```

Note that `key_a` and `key_b` are optional keys mapped to dictionaries and may or may not exist.

I have a function that checks if an outer key exists in `some_json` and returns a boolean.

```
CREATE FUNCTION key_exists(some_json json, outer_key text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN (some_json->outer_key IS NULL);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: json -> boolean
```

Why is `outer_key` equating to a boolean? What's the proper syntax to perform this check?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your function does the exact opposite of what the name is, but the way to fix your function is to add `(` and `)` around the `some_json->outer_key`.

Here is it fully functioning, and matching the name of your function (notice the `NOT` in front of the `NULL`).

```
CREATE FUNCTION key_exists(some_json json, outer_key text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN (some_json->outer_key) IS NOT NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Some tests:

```
select key_exists('{"key_a": {"nested_key": "a"}, "key_b": {"nested_key": "b"}}'::json, 'key_a');
 key_exists 
------------
 t
(1 row)
```

And here when a key doesn't exist:

```
select key_exists('{"key_a": {"nested_key": "a"}, "key_b": {"nested_key": "b"}}'::json, 'test');
 key_exists 
------------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Got it working, thanks! Such a simple fix yet easy to overlook. Also good catch on the name.

Answer (score 163):

You can also use the '?' operator like that:

```
SELECT '{"key_a":1}'::jsonb ? 'key_a'
```

And if you need to query by nested key, use like this:

```
SELECT '{"key_a": {"nested_key": "a"}}'::jsonb -> 'key_a' ? 'nested_key'
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

**NOTE**: Only for `jsonb` type.

Comment: Note when using this in a service that prepares the SQL statements (e.g. Metabase), it won't work, but you might be able to use `??` instead of `?`.

Comment: This seems like a much better answer, given a key that has a value of null will come back as true, which is expected.

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL 14 add subscripting feature for json/jsonb.

`SELECT ('{"key_a":1}'::jsonb) ['key_a'] is not null;`

return `t`.

Answer (score 4):

To check key exists or not you can use the operator -> this is used to get Get JSON object field by key
For example:

```
actual json data in column(attribute): {
    "active": "t",
    "email_address": "kris.ann.augdahl@hp.com",
    "pin": "2233"
}

SELECT attributes::json->'email_address'
FROM entity
WHERE entity_id = 55;
```

You can also search key via operator #> and #>>

Get JSON object field as text: '{"a":1,"b":2}'::json->>'b' by using the operator ->>

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres, if you select a key that does not exist it will return null.
so u can check the existence of a key by checking the null value of that key.

```
select '{"key_a": {"nested_key": "a"},
    "key_b": {"nested_key": "b"}}'::jsonb->>'a'
------------
null
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **select all rows where jsonb key exists** you can just use such query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_jsonb_field->'my_key' is not null
```