# MongoDB {"$exists": false} equivalent in Postgres

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, postgresql-json

MongoDB has an $exists operator to check if a key exists in the document or not. It works with `true` and `false`.

Postgres can also have JSON data stored. What is the Postgres equivalent for the following Mongodb Query?

```
db.myDocs.find_one({'myKey': { '$exists': False }})
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data (including table structures) and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. (please [edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: this question seems to be answered already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471625/fastest-check-if-row-exists-in-postgresql

Comment: @R2D2 the question you mentioned is about checking a row by an id, the OP here wants to check if a key exists or not

Comment: maybe this one then :) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921355/how-do-i-check-if-a-json-key-exists-in-postgres   , something like: SELECT '{"key_a":1}'::jsonb ? 'key_a'

Comment: yes, in case the OP wants to check a subfield of a json field, in my answer I posted the equivalent query of `db.myDocs.findOne({'myKey': { '$exists': false }})` for both cases

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have a table (note `json` type):

```sql
create table MY_TABLE (
    ID int not null,
    JSON_VALUE json not null 
);
```

with data:

```sql
insert into MY_TABLE (ID, JSON_VALUE) values (1, '{"myKey":"should be found", "otherKey":"123"}');
insert into MY_TABLE (ID, JSON_VALUE) values (2, '{"somethingElse":"should not"}');
```

you can use [postgre json function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html) to get all the IDs of

```sql
select ID from 
(select ID, json_extract_path(JSON_VALUE, 'myKey') AS keys from MY_TABLE) t

where keys is null -- equivalent to {'myKey': { '$exists': False }}
-- or
where keys is not null -- equivalent to {'myKey': { '$exists': True }}
```

to clarify the result of sub-query: `select ID, json_extract_path(JSON_VALUE, 'myKey') AS keys from MY_TABLE` would be:

```
id  keys
1   should be found
2   (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a top level field you can add a `where` clause:

```
select * from myDocs
where column_name is null
limit 1;
```

And if you want to check a subfield of a json field you can use the jsonb [`?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) operator:

```
select * from myDocs
where column_name::jsonb ? 'myKey' is false -- or
-- where column_name::jsonb ? 'myKey' = false
limit 1;
```

> jsonb ? text → boolean
>
> Does the text string exist as a top-level key or array element within the JSON value?

Answer (score 0):

Example of table

```
CREATE TABLE example_table(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    json_data JSON NOT NULL
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, json_extract_path(json_data, 'myKey') AS jsonKey
FROM example_table) t WHERE jsonKey IS NULL
```

similar to:

```
db.myDocs.find({'myKey': { '$exists': false }})
```

you can view more information on the commands for [Postgres JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)